# how to mock a class whose instance is created using new

Tags: typescript, mocking

```
export class myMainClass {

    async sampleMethod(req, res):Promise<any>{
        const result = await new HelperClass().randomMethod()
    }
}
```

while writing the unit test case for sampleMethod, how to mock the helper class method?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify which testing package you using, here's Jest solution

Create a manual mock by saving a mock implementation in the **mocks** folder. This allows you to specify the implementation, and it can be used across test files.

```
// __mocks__/HelperClass.js

// Import this named export into your test file:
export const mockRandomMethod = jest.fn();
const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {randomMethod: mockRandomMethod};
});

export default mock;
```

Import the mock and the mock method shared by all instances:

```
// myMainClass.test.js
import HelperClass, {mockRandomMethod} from './HelperClass';
import myMainClass from './myMainClass';
jest.mock('./HelperClass'); // HelperClass is now a mock constructor

beforeEach(() => {
  // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
  HelperClass.mockClear();
  mockRandomMethod.mockClear();
});


it('We can check if the consumer called a method on the class instance', () => {
  const myMainClassInstance = new myMainClass();
  myMainClassInstance.sampleMethod();
  expect(mockRandomMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[Jest Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock)

Comment: Hi Medet, I have tried the above solution, but didn't worked for me. I'm using jest framework for unit testing